# What is the max size of a mongodb query result array?

Tags: mongodb

I cannot find the answer to this seemingly basic question. The documentation says the max size for a BSON document is 16MB.

I want to know what is the max size of a *query result* allowed. E.g., if there are 1,000 records in a collection, and each document is 1MB, will mongodb throw an error if there are 400 documents (totaling to 400MB)?

Comment: I don't think there is any practical limit.